# Generating separate bibliographies per chapter with refsegment doesn't work

Tags: biblatex

I want to print a bibliography for each chapter. Reading the manual and a couple of answers here, I concluded that I should be using the `refsegment` functionality. Unfortunately, it doesn't work as I expected it to.

Here is the code I'm using:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
@article{wombat2016,
    author   = {Walther Wombat and Klaus Koala},
    title    = {The true meaning of 42},
    journal  = {Journal of modern skepticism},
}
@book{lion2010,
    author       = {Laura Lion and  Gabrielle Giraffe and Carl Capybara},
    title        = {The dangers of asking the wrong question},
    publisher    = {publishing house},
}
@online{wikibook,
    title        = {Generating Bibliographies with biblatex and biber},
    date         = {2016},
    url          = {https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Generating_Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[refsegment=chapter]{biblatex}
\bibliography{refs.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

Blabla~\cite{wombat2016}.
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment, heading=subbibliography]

\chapter{Further thoughts}

Blubbblubb~\cite{lion2010, wikibook}.
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment, heading=subbibliography]

\appendix
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And this is the result for the first chapter after running lualatex, biber, lualatex. I would have expected only the third entry to show up. What am I doing wrong here?
[image]

Comment: works fine for me, I get only entry [3]. Is your system up-to-date?

Comment: works fine for me too!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the MWE is working properly and it's probably related to a local issue.

Comment: Hmpf. It is the version from Debian stable, so texlive 2019, lualatex 1.07 and biblatex 3.12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the MWE works fine with a current version of `biblatex` (v3.14 from 2019/12/01) and `scrbook` (v3.29 from 2020/01/24). If possible you may want to consider updating your TeX system to get the current versions.

If that is not possible you can try the workaround discussed at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/857.

The workaround should be removed if you update to a newer version of `biblatex`, so in the MWE I added some code to produce an error if the version of `biblatex` is new enough.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[refsegment=chapter]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackagelater{biblatex}{2019/08/17}
  {\blx@error
     {Remove the redefinition of \string\blx@refpatch@chapter}
     {Your version of biblatex does not need the redefinition
      of \string\blx@refpatch@chapter}}
  {\def\blx@refpatch@chapter#1{%
     \ifundef\chapter
       {\blx@err@nodocdiv{chapter}}
       {\pretocmd\@makechapterhead{#1}
          {}
          {\blx@err@patch{\string\@makechapterhead}}
        \pretocmd\@makeschapterhead{#1}
          {}
          {\blx@err@patch{\string\@makeschapterhead}}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{wombat2016,
    author   = {Walther Wombat and Klaus Koala},
    title    = {The true meaning of 42},
    journal  = {Journal of modern skepticism},
}
@book{lion2010,
    author       = {Laura Lion and  Gabrielle Giraffe and Carl Capybara},
    title        = {The dangers of asking the wrong question},
    publisher    = {publishing house},
}
@online{wikibook,
    title        = {Generating Bibliographies with biblatex and biber},
    date         = {2016},
    url          = {https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Generating_Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}

Blabla~\cite{wombat2016}.
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment, heading=subbibliography]

\chapter{Further thoughts}

Blubbblubb~\cite{lion2010, wikibook}.
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment, heading=subbibliography]

\appendix
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Note that `\bibliography` takes the file name of your `.bib` file without file extension, so `\bibliography{refs.bib}` is incorrect, it should be `\bibliography{refs}`. Nowadays, it is usually preferred to use `\addbibresource` instead of `\bibliography` with `biblatex`. `\addbibresource` takes the name *with* file extension, so the preferred method would be

```
\addbibresource{refs.bib}
```